# CSS view-port media query turns off horizontal scrolling in IE on Windows Phone

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

To show responsive layout properly in IE in Modern UI in Windows 8, we need the following CSS:

```
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width;}
```

Source: [IE10 Snap Mode and Responsive Design](http://timkadlec.com/2012/10/ie10-snap-mode-and-responsive-design/)

This works as expected but it also turns off horizontal scrolling on wider tables on my site when viewed on Windows Phone 8 (horizontal scrolling works on all desktop browsers including IE). I also use view-port meta tag. Does anyone know how to correct this problem?

This is how I scroll tables horizontally in narrower layout:

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
    <table>
    ....
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following CSS to restrict the media query to large screens only:

```
@media all and (min-device-width:800px){
    @-ms-viewport{
        width:device-width;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly on both desktop and mobile IE. Tables scroll horizontally as expected.